# Recompile Delphi 64-bit vcl250.bpl

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, bpl

I wish to make a fix to StyleUtils.inc in Delphi Tokyo. My project is linking with runtime packages.

My app is 64-bits and so I would like to rebuild the vcl250.bpl in the ..\Redist\win64 directory.

I do realize that StyleUtils.inc is listed as not 64-bit compatible at the top of the file.

```
//TODO -oUnassigned -cImplement : x64 : Implement PlatformNotImplemented in this unit or disable for x64.
```

However, until some changes were made in Tokyo, the code had been very stable in Berlin. The error has been reported in the Quality Portal.

So the specific question is how would one rebuild the 64-bit vcl250.bpl redistributable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The licence is quite clear on this point. You are not permitted to distribute modified versions of the RTL/VCL/FMX runtime packages. So what you are trying to achieve can't be done.

At best you can deal with this by way of a runtime code hook.

Comment: Although this is a good point to mention, the OP didn't actually say anything about wanting to distribute the result.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think this would end up down a legal path rather than a technical one. I am curious how there is included a BuildWinRTL.dproj in ..\source\rtl. I had thought purpose of this file would have been to rebuild the rtl250.bpl. But then this couldn't be distributed? Thanks for the clarification on the licence.

Comment: I would expect that project builds dcus rather than runtime packages

Comment: Possibly or maybe to build a design-time package. Either way, I'll look for a possible runtime hook per your previous advice. Thanks.

Comment: `BuildWinRTL` would create a huge package called, well, `BuildWinRTL`. It would not recompile `vcl250.bpl`. It is obviously meant to recompile the DCUs listed in the `contains` section.

Comment: @hvd I guess I took a leap from the word "redistributable"